# Object-oriented matplotlib usage mysteriously produces boxplots without whiskers or median lines

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

I'm trying to use Python and matplotlib to define a custom class that 
produces a complex figure. However, I'm having trouble getting the 
boxplots to print correctly - they keep appearing without whiskers or 
lines marking the median values. I can't embed a sample image, but you can [see one here](http://cl.ly/0E3L0D1W272Q0F0D0O0O).

My custom class is defined as follows:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FixedLocator
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_svg import FigureCanvasSVG as FigureCanvas
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.optimize

class DotDashHist(Figure):
    """A Tufte-style dot-dash plot with histograms along the x- and y-axes."""
    def __init__(self, the_vals):
        # Actually inherit all the attributes and methods of parent class
        super(DotDashHist, self).__init__()
        # Process incoming data
        self.vals = the_vals
        self.xvals, self.yvals = zip(*self.vals)
        self.xvals_uniq = list(set(self.xvals))
        self.yvals_uniq = list(set(self.yvals))
        self.xmax = float(max(self.xvals_uniq))
        self.xpadding = float(self.xmax / 50)
        self.ymax = float(max(self.yvals_uniq))
        self.ypadding = float(self.ymax / 50)
        self.xlims = [-1 * self.xpadding, self.xmax + self.xpadding]
        self.ylims = [-1 * self.ypadding, self.ymax + self.ypadding]
        self.lims = [-1 * self.xpadding, self.xmax + self.xpadding,
                     -1 * self.ypadding, self.ymax + self.ypadding]
        # Set some matplotlib default behavior
        mpl.rcParams['backend'] = 'SVG'
        mpl.rcParams['lines.antialiased'] = True
        mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = 'sans-serif'
        mpl.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = 'Gill Sans MT Pro, Lucida Grande, Helvetica, sans-serif'
        mpl.rcParams['axes.titlesize'] = 'large'
        mpl.rcParams['axes.labelsize'] = 'xx-small'
        mpl.rcParams['xtick.major.size'] = 2
        mpl.rcParams['xtick.minor.size'] = 0.5
        mpl.rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 'xx-small'
        mpl.rcParams['ytick.major.size'] = 2
        mpl.rcParams['ytick.minor.size'] = 0.5
        mpl.rcParams['ytick.labelsize'] = 'xx-small'
    def _makeskel(self):
        # Set up the framework in which the figure will be drawn
        # Define the canvas for the figure
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self)
        self.set_canvas(self.canvas)
        # Place subplots on a 6x6 grid
        gs = GridSpec(6,6)
        # Add the main subplot, override weird axis and tick defaults
        self.main = self.add_subplot(gs[1:, :-1])
        self.main.set_frame_on(False)
        self.main.get_xaxis().tick_bottom()
        self.main.get_yaxis().tick_left()
        self.main.axis(self.lims)
        # Add the x-value histogram, override weird axis and tick defaults
        self.xhist = self.add_subplot(gs[0, :-1])
        self.xhist.set_xticks([])
        self.xhist.set_yticks([])
        self.xhist.set_frame_on(False)
        self.xhist.get_xaxis().tick_bottom()
        self.xhist.get_yaxis().tick_left()
        self.xhist.set_xlim(self.xlims)
        # Add the y-value histogram, override weird axis and tick defaults
        self.yhist = self.add_subplot(gs[1:, -1])
        self.yhist.set_xticks([])
        self.yhist.set_yticks([])
        self.yhist.set_frame_on(False)
        self.yhist.get_xaxis().tick_bottom()
        self.yhist.get_yaxis().tick_left()
        self.yhist.set_ylim(self.ylims)
    def _makehist(self):
        # Draw the x- and y-value histograms
        self.xhist.hist(self.xvals, normed=1, bins=min([50, self.xmax + 1]), 
                        range=[0, self.xmax + self.xpadding])
        self.yhist.hist(self.yvals, normed=1, bins=min([50, self.ymax + 1]),
                        range=[0, self.ymax + self.ypadding], 
                        orientation='horizontal')
    def makebox(self):
        self._makeskel()
        self._makehist()
        # Aggregate to make boxplots
        box_dict = {}
        for point in self.vals:
            if point[0] <= self.xmax and point[1] <= self.ymax:
                box_dict.setdefault(round(float(point[0]), 0), 
                        []).append(point[1])
        self.main.boxplot(box_dict.values(), positions=box_dict.keys(), 
                whis=1.0, sym='ro')
        self.main.set_xticks(np.arange(0, self.xmax + 1, 12))
        self.main.xaxis.set_minor_locator(FixedLocator(self.xvals_uniq))
        self.main.yaxis.set_minor_locator(FixedLocator(self.yvals_uniq))
```

This test code displays the problem:

```
from numpy.random import randn
import mycustomfigures as hf
test_x = np.arange(0, 25, 0.01)
test_y = test_x + randn(2500)
test_data = zip(test_x, test_y)
test_fig = hf.DotDashHist(test_data)
test_fig.makebox()
test_fig.suptitle('Test Figure')
test_fig.savefig('testing.svg')
```

What's wrong with the way I've defined DotDashHist? I can produce whiskered boxplots using the MATLAB-style stateful syntax, but that approach generates a tremendous amount of code when drawing multiple figures.

Comment: I don't understand why you're subclassing `Figure` for this?

Comment: I'm relatively new to Python and just started learning matplotlib, so all I can say is that it seemed sensible to me. I'm trying to produce a figure with 3 subplots, so I subclassed Figure. Is there a more sensible way to do this?

Comment: Well, there's no good reason to subclass Figure for it (though you could do it that way).  It's probably better (and much less verbose) to just make a stand-alone class and initiate a Figure instance as `self.fig`.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. It's too much to hope for that making this change will also fix my boxplots, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whiskers are in your original plot for me, they're just obscured by the outlier points you have plotted.

At any rate, I'd proceed a bit more like this:

```
import collections
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
import numpy as np

def main():
    x = np.arange(0, 25, 0.01)
    y = x + np.random.randn(x.size)
    plot = DotDashHist(figsize=(10, 8))
    plot.plot(x, y, whis=1.0, sym='r.')
    plot.title('This is a Test')
    plt.show()

class DotDashHist(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.fig = plt.figure(**kwargs)
        gs = GridSpec(6, 6)
        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(gs[1:, :-1])
        self.topax = self.fig.add_subplot(gs[0, :-1], sharex=self.ax)
        self.rightax = self.fig.add_subplot(gs[1:, -1], sharey=self.ax)
        for ax in [self.topax, self.rightax]:
            ax.set_axis_off()

    def plot(self, x, y, **kwargs):
        _, _, self.topbars = self.topax.hist(x, normed=1, bins=50)
        _, _, self.rightbars = self.rightax.hist(y, normed=1, bins=50,
                                                 orientation='horizontal')
        boxes = collections.defaultdict(list)
        for X, Y in zip(x, y):
            boxes[int(X)].append(Y)

        kwargs.pop('positions', None)
        self.boxes = self.ax.boxplot(boxes.values(), **kwargs)

    def title(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.topax.set_title(*args, **kwargs)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Joe - even with the flying points off, I didn't get the whiskers with my original code. Your solution works perfectly, though, and it's much shorter!

Comment: Huh, no idea, then... Maybe it's a matplotlib version issue?  At any rate, glad my example worked for you!

Comment: I think it's a problem with my SVG backend - both versions work fine with the Agg backend and the interactive display, but neither works with SVG. Since SVG isn't crucial, I'll take your example as inspiration and go from there. Thanks again...